# How to set custom_field value from product page to quote after a product added to cart in magento 2?

Tags: event-observer, sales-order, custom-attributes, sales-quote, magento2.4.1

I have a custom_field on the product details page( Like a hidden field ). Which is not a product attribute.
I can get this field value using **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event using an observer like this.

```
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="CartProductAddAfter" instance="Ayakil\ProductsSubscription\Observer\Checkout\CartProductAddAfter"/>
</event>
```

**Observer file**

```
class CartProductAddAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->_request = $request;
}public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {               
    
    $postData = $this->_request->getParams();       
    $frequencies = $postData['frequencies'];
}
```

}

My question is I have a custom field( **subcribe_frequency** ) in quote_item, How can I set this  **$frequencies** quote items after adding the products to the cart?

Please someone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the following code:

```
public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {

    $postData = $this->_request->getParams();
    $frequencies = $postData['frequencies'];
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $item->setSubcribeFrequency($frequencies);
}
```

Comment: can i use checkout_cart_product_add_after for $observer->getQuoteItem() ?

Comment: Yes, this example for checkout_cart_product_add_after event